# Arriving at airport on time

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

This question is regarding "on time" and "in time" with a specific example.

Consider, if a train is scheduled to leave at 9:00,it leaves on time, and you arrive at the station at 9:00.Thus you miss the train because you don't have enough time to check-in processes.

I was just wondering would you say

> "I arrived at airport/station on time."

to imply you arrived at station exactly in the same when the train leaves or an airplane takes off.Without further explanation do native speakers even assume you were there in time or is it clear you were late.Can Being "on time" be used in negative context?

Is it more idiomatic to say

> I couldn't arrive at airport in time.

even though you missed it for almost a few seconds.

Another example can be

"I arrived at school on time for exam but I couldn't enter to exam because I had to be there 15 minutes earlier the exam starts."

---

So how would you say " I miss it because I am late for a few second/minutes".I mean what is opposite phrase of "in the nick of time" or can we use it for negative sentences?

Comment: *nick of time* is a set phrase usage.  It is not related to your question.

Comment: @user3169 I meant can I say "I missed the train in the nick of time"

Comment: No, *nick of time* has a positive context or can be used with a negative verb form. I arrived *in the nick of time* or I did not arrive *in the nick of time*. But this really should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: @Murat No, that usage would not be idiomatically correct.

Comment: You could use something like "made my flight (or missed my flight) by a whisker/hairsbreadth."

Comment: @JasonPatterson Thank you Jason.I googled and learned "by the skin of my teeth" too. "by a whisker/hairsbreadth/by the skin of my teeth" can be used in positive and negative context contrary to "in the nick of time" which is used in positive context.By the way when you say "you made your flight by a whisker" it means you didn't miss the plane, doesn't it?

Comment: @Murat If you made the flight, then you did not miss the plane, "by a whisker" describes how little time was left before the plane was due to depart.  :-)  I've always liked "by the skin of my teeth."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite of "nick of time" is "I *just* missed it" (usually with that emphasis on "just") or "I just barely missed it."  E.g., "I got to the airport on time but the security line was so long I just barely missed my flight! Argh!" (The "on time" will be perceived, in these days, as "ahead of when the flight was supposed to depart, with enough time (theoretically) to get through the security scanners.")

In general, arriving "on time for [something]," without any explanation, will be perceived as arriving at the right time to achieve the goal -- a test, transport, doctor's appointment -- even if you have to arrive "early" from the nominal time. How much early? You'd have to explain that part. (E.g., "I was on time for my doctor's appointment -- 15 minutes early, so I had time to fill out the paperwork." "I got to the airport on time -- 2 hours before the flight, since the website said I should allow for that much time to make it through security.")

If you arrive "in time," then that has connotations that you were rushing, or that you barely made it (perhaps without knowing that the timing was getting "tight"!). E.g., "I made it to the airport in time, though I thought I was going to be an hour early! Those security lines were huge." "I got home in time to sign for the package, even though it was a day early!" "I made it to my connecting flight in time, hooray! Now let me catch my breath from running."

Answer (score 1):

Using *in time* has an expectation of what you would be *in time* for.

*on time* is just a statement of fact.

In your scenario:
*If a train is scheduled to leave at 9:00,it leaves on time, and you arrive at the station at 9:00.Thus you miss the train because you don't have enough time to check-in processes.*,

I would use:

> I did not arrive at *the* airport/station **in** time, therefore I missed the train. I will be late for the meeting.

To use *on time*:

> I arrived at the train platform **on time**.